# Omitting y-axis ticks (and labels) in base R

Tags: r, plot, graphics

#### The Question:

Imagine I am making a simple plot: `plot(1:5,1:5,ylab = "y-axis")`. Here, the y-axis (well actually both axis) are not only nicely labeled, but they both have tick marks with labels. How would I go about making a plot with neither tick marks nor tick mark labels?

#### What I've tried

The first thing I've tried was removing the margins to the left of the graph, while this effectively worked, it was a bit hacky and didn't get at what my actual problem was. I then continued to dive into the `par` specifications. Setting `par(tck = 0)` removes y-axis tick marks, but does so by removing *all* tick marks on the graph - this isn't ideal. I also tried `par(ann = FALSE)`, and `par(cex.lab = 0.001, cex.axis = 0.001)` which also did not work.

I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is burried somewhere in the par specifications but for now, unfortunately, I will have to stick with removing the left margins to 'cut off' these undesirable labels.

Comment: set `axes = FALSE` then run `box()`

Comment: @RichardTelford Great, worked nicely. Thank you.